# JsonSubType does not serialize to appropriate class

Tags: java, json, jackson, jackson-databind

"I am trying to use JsonInclude and SubType for serialization and deserialization. It seems to work when I pass type attribute from Postman as "A" or "B". I added new type "C" which also bounds to class A.class. However, it fails to create it and creates a default class (B.class) instead. I am not whats wrong with it. Documentation does not say we cannot have two different names bound to same class.

```
@JsonInclude(Include.NON_EMPTY)
    @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
    @JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, property = "type", visible = true, defaultImpl = B.class)
    @JsonSubTypes({@JsonSubTypes.Type(value = B.class, name = "B"),
            @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = A.class, name = "A"),
            @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = A.class, name = "C")})
    public abstract class U implements Serializable {

    ...
    ...
    abstract Role getRole();

    @JsonProperty("type")
    String type;

    Getters and Setters

    }

    @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY)
    @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
    @JsonTypeName
    public class A extends U implements Serializable {
    ....
    public Role getRole() {
      String type = getType();
      switch(type) {

       case "A" :
                return Role.A;
       case "C" :
                return Role.C;
       default  :
                throw new RuntimeException();
      }
     }
   }
```

Some more information. Depending on the type "A,C". I determine the role.

I am getting Casting error as I am expecting class A to be created but creates class B instead (the default one). Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: This should have worked in new Jackson version 2.6 but it is not working for me. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18394819/jackson-polymorphism-how-to-map-multiple-subtypes-to-the-same-class

Comment: The `switch` statement in `getRole` is trying to reproduce the behavior that should usually be obtained using typing/inheritance. It would be cleaner to have `class A { getRole() { return Role.A; } }` and  `class C { getRole() { return Role.C; } }` and the issue will disappear by itself.

Comment: Yea. That is one of the cleaner approach. However, I am avoiding that so I do not end up making CRUD changes to entire repository just by adding a class C where only the role differs.

Comment: I have added jackson databind 2.6.2 dependency explicitly. I did gradle dependencies to show me dependency tree. It is pulling in the data bind dependency.