# how to avoid getting an extra field with random information when using jackson Subtypes?

Tags: json, kotlin, jackson

I am trying to use JSON Subtypes to create some sort of "generic" object recipients for different events.

At the moment I have something like this:

```
 @JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, property = "color")
    @JsonSubTypes(
            JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Color::class, name = "RED"),
            JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Color::class, name = "YELLOW"),
            JsonSubTypes.Type(value = SpecialColor::class, name = "SPECIAL_1"),
            JsonSubTypes.Type(value = SpecialColor::class, name = "SPECIAL_2"),
            JsonSubTypes.Type(value = CustomColor::class, name = "CUSTOM")
        )


    interface EventColor{
        val eventId: String
        val color: ColorType
    }

    enum class ColorType {
        RED, YELLOW
    }
```

then I have my objects

```
data class Color(
    @get:JsonProperty override val eventId: String,
    @get:JsonProperty override val color: ColorType
): EventColor
```

the problem comes when I do a new instance of Color

```
Color("123", ColorType.RED)
```

when I print the object I get the right info

```
Color(eventId=event123, ColorType.RED)
```

but when I do

```
private val mapper = jacksonObjectMapper()
val mapped = mapper.writeValueAsString(myObject)
```

and print my object I get this

```
{"color":"RED","eventId":"event123","color":"YELLOW"}
```

this is the import for my mapper

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.module.kotlin.jacksonObjectMapper
```

I have no idea what's going on or how is this even possible, any idea what I could be doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Those two annotations `@JsonSubTypes.Type` with the same class don't make sense. I would expect an error, but apparently they didn't test this scenario and the first one simply gets ignored. So your annotation says "when serializing an `EventColor`, if it's a `Color`, add `"color":"YELLOW"`" (and when deserializing an `EventColor`, make it a `Color` if it has `"color":"YELLOW"`).

If `Color` is really the only implementation of `EventColor`, I believe the correct annotation is

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NONE, defaultImpl = Color::class)
interface EventColor{
    val eventId: String
    val color: ColorType
}
```

Or just remove the interface and use `Color` directly.

Comment: thanks for the reply @Alexey , unfortunately, Color is not the only implementation of EventColor, as there are couple of others, some  ColorType share the same class as they are simple but others are more complex and have their own properties. You think it still could work this way?

Comment: Again, in your edit you still have 2 subtype annotations for `Color` and 2 subtype annotations for `SpecialColor`. This can't work. How do you want the JSON for `Color` and for `SpecialColor` to look? And what does `SpecialColor` itself look like?

Comment: _If_ you want to express something like "if `color` is `RED` or `YELLOW`, use `Color`, if it's `SPECIAL_1` or `SPECIAL_2`, use `SpecialColor` etc." then I don't think there is any built-in support, you'll need to write your own `TypeResolverBuilder` and use [`@JsonTypeResolver`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.4/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/annotation/JsonTypeResolver.html) annotation.

Comment: (note: normally the property you discriminate on isn't part of the objects themselves, you'd have something like `"type":"simple"`/`"special"`/`"custom"` to decide which class to use)

Comment: the class for Red or Yellow should look the same but only having different information inside. I just checked again and seems this answer is still valid https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18394819/jackson-polymorphism-how-to-map-multiple-subtypes-to-the-same-class

Comment: This is quite surprising to me, thanks! Maybe you just need to use `include = JsonTypeInfo.As.EXISTING_PROPERTY` in your `@JsonTypeInfo`?